# Java Method only displays output once

Tags: java, class, for-loop, methods

I have this method:

```
public String getProduct() {
    String prod = null;
    for (LineItem item : items) {
        prod = item.getProduct().getDescription();
    }
    return prod;
}
```

which returns the description of my product but it only displays one product.

So for example if I have bought 3 products, it will only display one of them. Can anyone here advise me how I can alter my method so it shows all the product descriptions and not just one? So that it loops through and prints each product description.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: why are you returning `quantity` when it is not even set in this method?

Comment: simple typing mistake

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for (LineItem item : items ) {
    prod = item.getProduct().getDescription();
}
```

to

```
for (LineItem item : items ) {
    prod = item.getProduct().getDescription();
    System.out.println(prod);
}
```

Or make prod list of string and do

```
prod.add(item.getProduct().getDescription());
```

Ans print that list afterwards.

Comment: Thank you! Making a list and then printing it afterwards worked. Should have know to create a list. Happens when you code when you're tired... Shot

Answer (score 0):

Why do you return quantity?
If you want to return description of products then i can do follows:

```
public String getProduct() {
    String prod = "";
    for (LineItem item : items) {
        prod += item.getProduct().getDescription() + " ";
    }
    return prod;
}
```

Comment: Simple typing mistake... Thank you for your help. Appreciate it